# Duplicate an input in real time to another form field using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jsfiddle

Desired Action: Input from formElement2 to copy in real time into formElement4 using jQuery

```
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jGzF/17/)
```

Solution since asking question: `$('#formElement2').on('keyup change paste', function (e) {
    $('.copyText').val($(this).val())
});`

Result: It now changes in real time to what is typed in formElement2.

Comment: this html code is not valid. You should remove one '</div>'.

Comment: @alexeiTruhin—maybe, but that's a trivial error. The *center* element was deprecated in HTML 4 and is removed from HTML 5.

Answer (score 1):

Attach an [onkeyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) OR [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) to `formElement2` depending on how you want to do it.

```
<input type="text" id='formElement2' onkeyup="changeVal(this)">
```

In JS:

```
 <script>
      function changeVal(th){
         document.getElementById("formElement4").value=th.value;
      }
 </script>
```

So when you type something in `formElement2` it will copy the value and assign it to `formElement4`.

Comment: You are correct; however, you shouldn't have edited your code into the question.

Comment: What about where changing the value doesn't involve a keyup event?

Comment: @RobG. In that case `onchange` can be used. Updated my answer.

Comment: @JustinMorgan. Now I realized what you were saying. That was by mistake, sorry :)